# Can't build docker image: "requested access to the resource is denied"

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I can't push my docker image to my docker hub repository.

I am logged in. The repo exists and is public. I tried multipled ways of building/tagging/pushing my image.

```
docker login -u username -p password
docker build ./ -t my-image -f devops/Dockerfile
docker tag image username/my-image
docker push username/my-image
```

I crawled tens of questions on multiple websites. The answers were always either how to login correctly or how to tag and push the image. It seems to me like I am doing both correctly, so what's wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with 
   * Host OS and version
   * Docker version (docker version)
   * Output of docker info
   * Dockerfile 
   * The command you used to build/run the container, and any relevant output you saw 
    (masking any sensitive information)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you login with with your docker command ? something like this

```
echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
```

I guess you need to set the :latest tag on your image. And try to push it with the :latest tag. Also make a correct naming of the container.

> Note that only a-z0-9-_. are allowed when naming images:

```
docker tag myImage myusername/myimage:latest 
docker push myusername/myimage:latest
```

I did it this way and it worked for me.

Here is my example bash script for automate the image taging after a successful build and push it to the docker hub.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
docker build -t myusername/myimage:latest .
echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
docker push myusername/myimage:latest

docker tag myusername/myimage:latest myusername/myimage:1
docker push myusername/myimage:1

docker tag myusername/myImage:latest myusername/myimage:1.1
docker push myusername/myImage:1.1

docker tag myusername/myimage:latest myusername/myimage:1.1.1
docker push myusername/myimage:1.1.1
```

Comment: The problem was the format. My kebab case image name was not supported. Unfortunately there's no specific error message for this case... thanks

Comment: It's weird because for months I didn't have any problem with my kebab-case image, I could push it, and today it breaks. There must be something more to this but I don't know what.

Comment: Also, could you add the source of the quote to your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I usually only write

```
docker login
```

which then requests that you enter your details or says that it's using your existing details that have been saved in the system. Otherwise, I can't see any problems with your commands.

I'm not sure that just writing `docker login` will make any difference but can't see any other differences.

Comment: That's what I used to do too. Since it didn't work I tried writing the whole command, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could it be that docker build ./ -t myImage -f devops/Dockerfile is missing the whole path to the Dockerfile and not completing the build? Should be /devops/Dockerfile?

Comment: no this path is correct. David found the answer: my image name was incorrectly formatted (middlescore characters are not supported and I used some).